# installing rakudobrew on windows

Tags: git, github, raku

I try to install rakduobrew on windows system when i run the following get command :

```
git clone https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew %USERPROFILE%\rakudobrew
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: I just tried and didn't get that error. Please try again and let us know if you are still having that problem.

Comment: I don't get a git error when I try this. Can you clone other things? rakudobrew is really a core developer tool. If you just want Perl 6, [there are already MSI packages](https://rakudo.perl6.org/downloads/star/) for the latest Rakudo. [Rakudo * is chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/rakudostar) too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a stable download link instead of cloning yourself?
at the time of the writing, said version would be 2017.04, which can be downloaded here:
http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/

Comment: Actually, at the time of writing that would be 2017.04 :)

Comment: It looks like the files changed again: https://rakudo.org/files so Maybe update to 2018-04 and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

That was probably a temporary GitHub failure. Did you try again later?

Comment: Given this thread is already a year old, I think this is a waste of time.